# Почему встречается ошибка Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>.Model.get вернул null?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Столкнулся с проблемой. Решения в интернете не нашёл. У меня есть 2 таблицы прикрученые к WEB-API и EF Core. Мне нужно вывести вторую таблицу, однако, почему то Model.get возвращает null. При выводе первой таблицы всё работает. Код страницы razor pages:

```
@model IEnumerable<ABSoftTT.Models.tabelTwo>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Таблица спец. запроса";
}

<table class="table">
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Key</td>
            <td>@item.Count</td>
            <td>@item.CountMoreThenOne</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

> В строчке @foreach (var item in Model) Вылезает ошибка: System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.Model.get вернул null.

Код второй страницы анналогичен первой за некоторыми исключениями (передаваемыми данными)

Код страницы в контроллере:

```
public IActionResult SecondTabel()
        {
            return View();
        }
    

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SecondTabel(Counter counter)
        {
            try
            {
                var dataProvaider = new DataProvider();
                dataProvaider.InitializateSecondTable(); // формирование 2ой таблице на основе первой.
            }
            catch{ }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Я пробовал создавать объексты в ручную, а не с помощью команды:

> InitializateSecondTable()

Сам вопрос заключается в том, почему возвращается null и как это исправить? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `return View();` - никакие данные не передаются; получается null.

Comment: Что должно быть прописано в скобках? ```return View(ABSoftTT.Models.tabelTwo);```??

Comment: Во вюьхе у вас указано `@model IEnumerable<ABSoftTT.Models.tabelTwo>`. Значит туда нужно передавать коллекцию этих `tabelTwo`.

Comment: Добрый день. По рекомендации выше вылезает сообщение "tabelTwo" является тип, который недопустим в данном контексте. Строчка выглядит так:
`return View(tabelTwo);`